# Someone give the best answer to my question, but post it as a comment because the question is protected

Tags: discussion

Honestly I never thought that [my question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83591/in-the-300-movie-in-the-final-battle-why-didnt-leonidas-kill-xerxes) will receive so much attention, but it did.

The user [displayname](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/60110/displayname) wrote three related comments, and, in my opinion those comments provide the best answer to my question. I asked him/her why he/she didn't post it as an answer, and it is because the question is protected, and he/she comes from an other community.

The person suggested that I can copy paste it into a self answer, but it does not seem the correct way for me.

What can we do about this?

Comment: they have 101 rep so they have the association bonus but i would have thought that this would be counted for Protected questions

Comment: @Memor-X It isn't. You need 10 *on-site* reputation. But then again, that's a single answer on another question someone deems wirth an upvote, or 5 suggested improvements to existing content.

Comment: Personally, I'd ask the user to gain the 10 reputation. It's easy enough: 5 quick edits to questions/answers, or 2 upvotes on another question/answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Write it as a self answer, crediting the original user.

If you were to simply copy someone's answer, I can understand why this might seem wrong. However, in this case, *the original user has already given you full permission to do so*.

Copy the comments into an answer, credit the answer as quoting the original user, and mark it as accepted. That seems to be the best course of action.